# Context-free grammar derivations in C#

Tags: c#, grammar

I would like to ask if there's a C# framework for context-free grammar derivations. I just want to find out if there's a derivation (given the grammar) for a given word.

**Note:** Actually it should not be that hard to program but I'm short of time right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean a word in a natural (spoken) language, not a programming language right?

Comment: "A context-free grammar" is a very specific entity. What's the point of your question?

Comment: Mårten: Actually no, the "word" may contain numbers and other symbols not in alphabet

Comment: A device which determines if a given set of tokens is a valid sequence in a language determined by a CFG is called a "parser". A device which takes a grammar and produces a parser for it is called a "parser generator". If you do a search for "C# parser generator" that will help you find one.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the keyword!

Comment: @Blindy: I would like to be more specific but it is a company project I should not talk about :-(

Comment: @MartyIX, my comment wasn't aimed at you, but at the unhelpful first commenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://antlr.org/ is the de facto standard for managed languages pretty much.